# Emit value if specific time has passed after last item

Tags: java, kotlin, rx-java2, rx-android, rx-kotlin2

I've got an observable: `Observable.create<Boolean> {emitter = it}`, to which I push some values. I want it to publish a 'false' value, as soon as some specific time period has passed without any value being pushed to that emitter.

How is that possible with RxJava/Kotlin 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to combine 2 functions: `timeout` and `onErrorReturn`.

```
Observable.create<Boolean> { 
    // use emitter here
}
     .timeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
     .onErrorReturn { if (it is TimeoutException) false else throw it } 
     .subscribe { println("onNext $it") }
```

Updated snippet after clarification. `repeatWhen` will resubscribe to Observable.

```
Observable.create<Boolean> { 
    // use emitter here
}
    .timeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .onErrorReturn { if (it is TimeoutException) false else throw it }
    .repeatWhen { it }
    .subscribe { println("onNext $it") }
```

Comment: Can you make the timeout not terminating the observable?